# Linux installation in RAID

Tags: linux, raid, software-raid

I am a fairly new systems administrator and I have to configure the RAID on a Linux machine. From my understanding so far, RAID is an array of multiple disks. I have some questions though.

**Question 1:** If I have five *500 GB* HDD, these 5 HDDs together are termed as RAID disk.Is this right?

**Question 2:** I presume the machine is brand new with nothing inside it. So, I just have a machine with RAID solid state disk. If I have to install RHEL or Ubuntu or any linux distribution in these hard disks, how should I install? Should I install the OS in any one of the disk and use RAID tool like **Mdadm**?

**Question 3:** I believe the RAID disk is being configured for some software. So, is there any particular configuration I need to look out for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Question 1: If I have five 500 GB HDD, these 5 HDDs together are termed as RAID disk.Is this right?

From my experience 5 HDDs in a RAID is termed a "RAID array".

> Question 2 ... state disk. If I have to install RHEL or Ubuntu or any Linux distribution in these hard disks, how should I install? Should I install the OS in any one of the disk and use RAID tool like `mdadm`?

I've used RHEL/CentOS/Fedora and during the installation am given the opportunity to create the RAID array. I typically create it then, and then do the installation to the newly setup array.

> Question 3 I believe the RAID disk is being configured for some software. So, is there any particular configuration I need to look out for?

There are 2 types of RAID arrays. You can use hardware to do it, or use software. Given you tagged your quesiton as [software-raid](/questions/tagged/software-raid) I'm going to assume you're using the software variety, this is accomplished using a software package called mdm. The package used to administer is is called `mdadm`.

See the `mdadm` man page for more about it.